# function to exchange tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following paragraph in html code:

`<p id=tag1> html statements before click </p>`

... and I am trying to write function which would split the above paragraph to two paragraphs like this :

`<p id=tag1> html statements after click </p><p id=tag2></p>`

... with intention to exchange then *tag1* id with *tag2* id to have final result:

`<p id=tag2> html statements after click </p><p id=tag1></p>`

I am trying to achieve desired result by this function:

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("tag1").innerHTML = "html statements after click </p><p id='tag2'>";
        document.getElementById("tag2").id = "tagTmp";
        document.getElementById("tag1").id = "tag2";
        document.getElementById("tagTmp").id = "tag1";
    }
    </script>
```

... but this donesn't work to me. Problem is with the first step - innerHtml modification works different ways as expected and yealds following result:

```
<p id=tag1> html statements after click 
<p></p>
<p id=tag2></p>
</p>
```

... paragraph id=tag2 is still nested inside paragraph id=tag1 (I want to have the both paragraphs at the same level).

Is there any way to get requested functionality? Can you help please?
Thanks.

Comment: So, functionally, are you just wanting to add another paragraph tag after that existing paragraph tag?

Comment: yes, exactly, I want to add another paragraph tag after that existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("tag1").innerHTML = "html statements after click </p><p id='tag2'>";
```

So the reason this is not acting as you expect it to is because this is not changing the markup, as you think it is.  innerHTML does not include the open and close tags.  Your interacting with a dom node, so you can't close the parent node like that.  As you can see it tries to protect your weird request of a single </p> and creates a new open for it so it's paired.

If you were going to do this with jquery, as that's one of your post tags, it could possibly be something like...

```js
    //get the existing element
    var $originalTag = $('#tag1');
    //update its id
    $originalTag.prop('id', 'tag2');
    //create a new one after it with the original id
    $('<p id="tag1"></p>').insertAfter($originalTag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="tag1">An Existing Tag</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it could work, but trying it I get following error: 

TypeError: $originalTag.prop is not a function

... what is there problem pls?

Comment: Check the code snipplet.  Seems to work.  I think you got something else going on.  prop() was added in 1.6 so if your using an older version of jQuery that might be it.  In that case try using attr() instead of prop()

Comment: Thanks a lot, with 'attr()' instead 'prop()' it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for you

```
<html>

<div>
    <p id=tag1> html statements before click </p>
</div>

<script>

    var
        p = document.querySelector('p'),
        p2 = document.createElement('p');

    p2.id = 'p2';
    p2.textContent = ' p2...p2 '

    p.outerHTML += p2.outerHTML;

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. This example works, but how  can I specify which paragraph will be appended with the new one if there are already several paragraphs in document (distinguished by id)?

Comment: Chose the id you need instead of the 'p'

Comment: Sorry, but not being sure how exactly to modify your example to get it working as needed.  Would you please post complete example again with ids for both paragraphs - old and newly appended one too?